# PHP - fire tracking pixel from crontab - server side

Tags: php, cron, server, pixel

I'm having difficulties to fire an image pixel code from crontab (server side) using PHP
for example:

```
     <img src="http://www.company.com/tracking.php?p=abcdefg@abcdefg.com"/>
```

i tried using fput, curl and file_get_content every time i fire the pixel the "company.com" didn't receive the hit with the parameter.
but when i browsed the url itself they said that it worked as expected.

what is the preferred way to fire http or https (not postback) pixels from cron and php?
maybe i should use wget to fire the pixels?

Thanks,

Bentzy

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how company.com's tracking works, it could be several things.

One could be that it might only register hits for 'valid' browsers - e.g. it might look at the headers sent with the request and decided whether it's a valid hit or not based on that. That would probably be my guess.

You could try and fool it be sending headers along with your request - you should be able to do this using cURL and PHP. You can find more about cURL in the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Other than that, without knowing what company.com is, it's hard to say exactly how their tracking works. It could also be that it requires to set a cookie on the user's browser for it to register a hit, in which case this can also be done with cURL, but is a little involved.

Comment: it is an image tracking pixel type.
for example "HasOffers" pixel.
more info in here: http://support.hasoffers.com/hc/en-us/articles/202674378-Conversion-Tracking-Basics

Comment: What I say still stands - you need a session/cookie for the tracking to be recognised - file_get_contents isn't session/cookie aware and you need to specifically tell curl to use cookies